# How to save my JSON file after updating (resets after restart program)

Tags: json, node.js, object, save

So I'm trying to program something using Node.js, I've got a file that is called 'profile.json', that is an object. When something happens, I need to update a value of 'name' to a new name. So I do
'profile.name = name2;'
but after I restart my program everything comes back and I have to change it again. So my problem is how would I save the json after updating it?

Comment: How do you load the file? How do you parse it? Can you find functions that do the opposite of this?

Comment: const profile = require('./profile.json');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not saving because you are reading the file and updating it in the application. However, you are not changing anything in the file. Once you read the file and parse the JSON, no link exists to the original file. The JSON exists only in memory. You will want to use the NodeJS File System class to write the file. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html First, check if the file exists, if it does delete it (or move/rename). Second, save the file using the fs.writeFile method.

Comment: So.. I should create a file through the fs.writeFile, write to it the default variables and than I could change the values?

Comment: If you are doing it that way yeah. It sounds like you are using this JSON as a class model. But at this point I would ask why are you not using a database? MongoDB is a non-relational database that works with JSON and you can define your models in a JS file and save your modified json(records) in the DB. Or you could go relational and use PostgreSQL. Which has a JSON datatype. You could treat the entry like a BLOB and easily overwrite the JSON without worrying about your file system